# Override migration default value in Rails form input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am having a products table with default **min_quantity** is **0** and **max_quantity** is MAX INT number **999999999**.
When I tried to display this form, the default values from backened are displayed in the UI with min_quantity as 0 and max_quantity as 999999999.
How to leave this input fields as blank for the create action?

schema.rb:

```
create_table "products”, id: :integer, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name", null: false
  t.integer "min_quantity”, default: 0, null: false
  t.integer "max_quantity”, default: 999999999, null: false
end
```

products/_form.slim:

```
= simple_form_for([@product]) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name
    = f.input :min_quantity, label: 'Minimum Quantity'
    = f.input :max_quantity, label: 'Maximum Quantity'
```

I tried using  `value : nil` as:

```
-if f.object.new_record?
 = f.input :min_quantity, label: 'Minimum Quantity’, input_html: {value: nil}
-else 
= f.input :min_quantity, label: 'Minimum Quantity'
```

But when there is validation error, the values entered are getting disappeared. The same issue when I use jQuery.

So how can I handle this issue of overriding blackened values in Rails? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the behavior you want by setting the `min_quantity` and `max_quantity` to `nil` in the `new` method of the controller.

```
def new
  @product.min_quantity = @product.max_quantity = nil
end
```

The reason why the values of `min_quantity` and `max_quantity` are show when the validation fails is because they are set in the `@product` object so they actual values of the attributes are going to be shown when the form is reloaded